# Re-generate watermarked product images

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, magento2.2.4, watermark

For one of our clients, I want to change the watermark of the images to a better resolution image

```
in Design > Configuration > Product Image Watermarks.
```

My question, because I see no 're-generate product images' button, and no 'auto-re-generate' option, will these images be generated again automatically with the new watermark?